# Will there be Eddy currents in a conductive rotor with a magnet in it?

Tags: electromagnetism, rotation

I am desiging a turbine for a little experiment.

It consists of a plastic stator and a rotor that has a Halbach array inside it (see image). It would be nice to machine the rotor out of metal in order to be able to spin it faster (plastic will warp with time and so on).

The problem is that if Eddy currents form in this rotor, they will probably heat it up quite a bit (I'm aiming at spinning at $\sim$ 100 Hz or so).

**Would Eddy currents form in it?** It is clear that they would if the magnet and rotor were rotating at different angular velocities. But in this case, the flux is not changing in the rotating frame but it is in the lab frame... so it seems like a [Faraday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox), and I would like to know what you guys think would happen before I build it.

[image]